# QuickBooks RDS client (or maybe server) is throwing Public key exchange error: Object already exists

Tags: sdk, com, quickbooks

I am working with intuit SDK tech support on this without much luck. I was hoping someone here might know what object this error might be referring to.

I am basically sending a request from one computer to QuickBooks on another machine via PowerShell and Remote Data Sharing (RDS) Client/Server provided in the QuickBooks SDK. The relative portion of the Powershell script looks something like this..

```
$myQBXMLRP = New-Object -com QBXMLRP2.RequestProcessor
$myQBXMLRP.OpenConnection2("qb4D","CCFolioPro",2)
```

The first line instantiates the COM object QBXMLRP2.RequestProcessor. The second line opens a connection with QuickBooks. RDS Client on the local machine receives the OpenConnection request and passes it on to the RDS Server on the machine where QB resides which in turn opens the connection with QB. The second line is throwing the following error...

> Exception calling "OpenConnection2" with "3" argument(s): "Public key exchange error: Object already exists

Reading here in stackoverflow and elsewhere via google I see that this error occurs to other programmers not dealing in any way with QuickBooks, so I am hoping somone here might be able to help me figure out how to fix the problem.

I have QB/RDS working fine prior to this installation. So I know it should work as is. Something is hung up on this computer, the server computer, or ????

Thanks,

John

Comment: I have given up using RDS. Instead I have written my own link to a remote QB install within my integrated app. In my opinion RDS is not a reliable option to be counted on to work in differeng network configurations. Intuit SDK tech support was helpful in trouble shooting the problem and perhaps together we would have eventually resolved the issue, but I could not afford to wait any longer for a resolution. I will leave this question unanswered, unless the powers that be on this forum think I should delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Your mileage may vary. I cleared the following file, reboot and reinstall RDS then things are back to normal. It was on a Windows Server 2012 but you get the idea. You need to change your view options so these folders are not hidden. Worths a shot, and I hope this helps.

[Clear one of the key files created by RDS by prior runs or installations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RppJ8.png)

Comment: How do you know which one to clear? And by clear do you mean delete?

Comment: I deleted the file based on the most recent file date. And to be on the safe side, I suggest making a backup for the file you will delete in that folder.